# I am trying to import .js comp but it is showing following error

Tags: reactjs, import, native

Here is the code index.js

import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import StyledButton from "../StyledButton"; // here is the problem
import styles from './style';

const CarItem = (props) => (

```
    <ImageBackground
        source={require('../../assets/tesla/6.jpg')}
        style={styles.image} />

    <View style={styles.titles}>

        <Text style={styles.title}> Model G </Text>

        <Text style={styles.subtitles}> Starting from $50,000 </Text>

    </View>
    <StyledButton/>


</View>
```

);
export default CarItem;

**this is the error kinldy help**
Unable to resolve module ../StyledButton from C:\Users\Sufyyan\TeslaClone\Components\CarItem\index.js:

None of these files exist:

- Components\StyledButton(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
- Components\StyledButton\index(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  1 | import React from 'react';
  2 | import { View, Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

> 3 | import StyledButton from "../StyledButton";
> |                           ^
> 4 | import styles from './style';
> 5 |
> 6 | const CarItem = (props) => {